# How to proccess raw camera data in Android without NDK

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-ndk

Can i proccess raw RGB camera data in an Android device without using NDK+opencv?
I don't even need to change the displayed data, only to get information from it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can get get a still image from the camera. What information do you need/want?

Comment: Check this answer :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775942/android-sdk-get-raw-preview-camera-image-without-displaying-it

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, the image data comes in NV21-format from your `byte[] data`

Code taken from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html (`onPictureTaken` from `PictureCallback()`, but similar to `onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)` from `Camera.PreviewCallback`.

```
private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        //convert here and do other stuff like save the picture.
    }
};
```

In both cases you have to convert from NV21 to RGB in said methods, that you could implement like this: [Confusion on YUV NV21 conversion to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469730/confusion-on-yuv-nv21-conversion-to-rgb)