# How we can create a Background camera service using android hardware camera2

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have create camera Background service using android.hardware.camera but Camera class is depreciated so i cannot use in marshmallow.

Comment: use `android.hardware.camera2`? And check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/36779818/2686502

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Camera class is deprecated, but it still works fine.

Deprecated does not mean removed; just that it might eventually be removed, and that using camera2 is recommended whenever possible.