# Camera SetPreviewCallback best way to convert YUV to RGB

Tags: android, android-camera, rgb

I am using this code to write an image to SD after `camera.takePicture` is called:

```
protected String doInBackground(byte[]... jpeg) {
    File directory=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + getString(R.string.qpw_picture_path) + "/" + getString(R.string.qpw_picture_title) + "_" + initialTime);
    directory.mkdirs();
    String currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat(getString(R.string.qpw_date_format)).format(new Date());
    File photo = new File (directory, getString(R.string.qpw_picture_title) + "_" + currentTime + "_" + current + ".jpg");
    current++;

    if (photo.exists()) {
        photo.delete();
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());         
        fos.write(jpeg[0]);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    }

    new ImageMediaScanner(getBaseContext(), photo);
    return(null);
}
```

Which is working fine in this case, but when I am using the same code to write images from `camera.setPreviewCallback`, I end up with 450KB corrupted images on SD which cannot be used or even opened.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

It seems that data should be first converted from YUV to RGB before saving. Having tried one of the many code samples found on Google and SO, I was facing no more issues.

Does anyone know what is the best way of doing it? In terms of speed, memory allocation, CPU...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone stumbles on the same issue [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469730/confusion-on-yuv-nv21-conversion-to-rgb?lq=1) summarize well what I was looking for.