# Convert YBR_Full image to RGB in java

Tags: java, rgb, bytebuffer

I could get the array of byte contains the YUV values and perform the same method in( [Confusion on YUV NV21 conversion to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469730/confusion-on-yuv-nv21-conversion-to-rgb?lq=1) ) on it to get the array of int value represent RGB,and then i tried to convert this array to ByteBuffer so i can view it in JLabel. But what i can see is a separated vertical columns of Red, green, and Blue? Where is the wrong in my schema? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create Image and set it's value by using your array , then display the image in Jlabel

Like this :

```
    byte[] imageInByte;////////////this byte array contain your RGB
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
    BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
```

then You can display `bImageFromConvert` in JLabel

Like this :

```
 JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bImageFromConvert ));
```

Comment: before i edit my answer , x and y from for loop on the array which contain the RGB value

Comment: if i want to write it to file like this:
try{
    File outputfile = new File("saved.jpg");
    ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "jpg", outputfile);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
i got an exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: im == null!

Comment: actually i dont know ,i dont have any variable in this name

Comment: Sure you have a one but you cant find it , check on this variable first ,in  your exception you can find which line have the problem , or you can post the whole code to me

Comment: I find that the bImageFromConvert is null which cause this exception to appear when im trying to write to file

Comment: you should but your byte array in `bImageFromConvert` before you write it , so if the image is null may be your byte array is empty check it again