# How to apply photo effects/filters on Run time in android Camera?

Tags: java, android

Please suggest me How to apply photo effects/filters on Run time  in android Camera? with out using JNI , OpenGl and open CV. I need to apply effects only  through   Java code.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1.  Convert frame from NV21 to format supported by some image processing library. You can read how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469730/confusion-on-yuv-nv21-conversion-to-rgb) or [here](http://www.41post.com/3470/programming/android-retrieving-the-camera-preview-as-a-pixel-array)

Step 2. Use image processing library to perform filtering. For example you can use [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/). You can read about how to use ImageJ [here](http://www.rierol.net/imagej_programming_tutorials.html) or [here](http://www.gm.fh-koeln.de/~konen/WPF-BV/tutorial-ImageJ_V1.71.pdf) or [here](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Image Processing](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/) to apply various effects on Image. It provides various effects to be applied on Image after capturing.

Suppose i want to apply contrast effect on image then i will use the below method:

> ```
> public static Bitmap createContrast(Bitmap src, double value) {
>     // image size
>     int width = src.getWidth();
>     int height = src.getHeight();
>     // create output bitmap
>     Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
>     // color information
>     int A, R, G, B;
>     int pixel;
>     // get contrast value
>     double contrast = Math.pow((100 + value) / 100, 2);
>         // scan through all pixels
>     for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
>         for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
>             // get pixel color
>             pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
>             A = Color.alpha(pixel);
>             // apply filter contrast for every channel R, G, B
>             R = Color.red(pixel);
>             R = (int)(((((R / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
>             if(R < 0) { R = 0; }
>             else if(R > 255) { R = 255; }
>             G = Color.red(pixel);
>             G = (int)(((((G / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
>             if(G < 0) { G = 0; }
>             else if(G > 255) { G = 255; }
>             B = Color.red(pixel);
>             B = (int)(((((B / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
>             if(B < 0) { B = 0; }
>             else if(B > 255) { B = 255; }
>              // set new pixel color to output bitmap
>             bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
>         }
>     }
>     // return final image
>     return bmOut;
> }
> ```

Use above method as:

> ```
>     BitMap bmp =BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length); //Here you can define your image and convert it into Bitmap.
>       bmp = createContrast(bm,75);
>   mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I want to apply affects at run time only not after capturing  Image.

Comment: Yes you can do that using the codes which are provided in the link. After capturing you can set image in `ImageView` and apply the effects on it by creating method for different effects which are available in the given link.

Comment: AFAIK You can not apply effects run time on Image. You have to capture image first then and then you will be able to apply effects.

Comment: @GrlsHu we can do it by using JNI and open CV. but Srinoid is asking how to do by using Java

Comment: @android_dev Yes i know we can do it using JNI and openCV but Srinoid asking without using this libraries that is why i have provided this solution.

Comment: How can i apply those effects while running the camera.