# YUV_NV21_TO_RGB not working?

Tags: android, camera

I am staring to develop an app which monitors the camera preview, and does some image processing on it and displays int on a canvas. Just as a diagnostic I have the following code:

```
camera = Camera.open();

ImageFormat imf = new ImageFormat();
Camera.Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
param.setPreviewSize(128, 128);
preview_format = param.getPreviewFormat();
Camera.Size sz = param.getPreviewSize();

myimage = new int[sz.width*sz.height];
```

At run time it reports that preview_format is 17 which I understand is "NV21".

Later I have:

```
    camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback()
    {    
          public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] _data, Camera _camera)
          {
              YUV_NV21_TO_RGB(myimage , _data, 128, 128) ;
          }
    });
```

The function YUV_NV21_TO_RGB was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469730/confusion-on-yuv-nv21-conversion-to-rgb).

Meanwhile in another thread I have:

```
    canvas.drawBitmap(
            myimage,        // the int array
            0,              // where to start in the array
            128,            // the stride ???
            200,            // x coord of where to display
            200,            // y coord of where to display
            128,            // wid
            128,            // ht
            false,          // alpha used?
            null);          // the paint used
```

The resulting image can be seen amongst other diagnostics in the square below. The stripes change as I move the phone around and appear to in some way correspond to what the camera is pointing at, but clearly it has been mangled. I tried using an alternative function found [here](http://www.41post.com/3470/programming/android-retrieving-the-camera-preview-as-a-pixel-array), and another from wikipedia, but with seemingly identical results. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** One thought I had was that perhaps NV21 may not completely specify the format - maybe its a class of formats, where you need to go on and specify the bits per pixel or similar.

**EDIT:** An extra clue - if I cover the camera completely, the square goes entirely pure green.

[image: Output]

Comment: Are you sure the data you receive is for a 128 pixel wide NV21 encoded image? Either of these two parameters (width, format) isn't correct. Is onPreviewFrame() called with a byte array of 24,576 bytes?

Comment: _data appears to be 460800 bytes long according to the eclipse debugger.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Your preview size is 640 x 480 pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your preview size is not 128 by 128 because you fail to set it. You set it on the `Camera.Parameters` instance but you don't apply it to the camera.

You need to add the following line:

```
camera.setParameters(param);
```

And it's probably safe to get the parameters directly from the `Camera` instance:

```
preview_format = camera.getPreviewFormat();
Camera.Size sz = camera.getPreviewSize();
```

Comment: Bingo! I'm so embarrassed :-)