# Get raw RGB or YUV data buffer in Tango

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm just started with Tango and Unity, and need to find a way to get raw RGB or YUV data from the device camera in order to pass it further for processing. This processing requires me to provide either ARGB array or three Y,U,V buffers. How shall I approach this?

I need something similar to `OnTangoImageAvailableEventHandler` callback - however, it gives me an array of bytes which is a YUV image and I have no way of getting individual Y,U or V planes, neither strides for each plane.

Answer (score 0):

YUV byte array can be transformed to RGB using function mentioned here: 
[Confusion on YUV NV21 conversion to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469730/confusion-on-yuv-nv21-conversion-to-rgb).
Using that function you can get R, G and B values.

Comment: thanks! is there a way to get individual Y,U and V planes buffers?

Comment: In mentioned code values for Y, U, V are extracted before they are converted to R, G, B if that is what you need...