# Android Camera Filters

Tags: android, graphics, camera, android-camera

I wish to apply camera filters to camera preview.
As I understand, the solution can be to process byte stream incoming from the camera, decode it from YUV format to Bitmap and then pass frames to surface View, but for me it's unclear how to customize it. How can i create camera filter (ex. as in Instagram or other camera apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's an old question, but maybe someone will be looking for the same thing and might find this useful....

If you want to apply filter to the live preview, it's not easy, because the conversion from YUV to RGB is expensive and the performance is low  on android devices. Please check [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371055/apply-custom-filters-to-camera-output/8372731#8372731) on this topic and one other [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350230/android-how-to-display-camera-preview-with-callback).

If you only want to apply filter to a single taken image, it shouldn't be a problem, it's just a matter of image processing. The code will be similar to the examples in the linked questions.